# Showing/hiding elements in row when hovering the row

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, font-awesome

I have an HTML table that I create using angular-datatables. The HTML for the table looks like this

```
<table ng-if="devicesLoaded()" datatable="ng" class="device-table table table-hover" 
           dt-options="dtOptions" dt-column-defs="dtColumnDefs">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th ng-repeat="key in getParametersColumns()">{{key | capitalize}}</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="no-border" ng-repeat="item in data">
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
            <td>{{item.type}}</td>
            <td>
                <i class="fa fa-download action-icon" tooltip="Download" 
                   ng-click="Download(item)">
                </i>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>
```

I want the `<i>` element (the download button) to appear only when the specific row is hovered. Please note - not only when hovering the specific item or td, but when hovering over every point in the row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a hover:

```
tr.no-border i.action-icon{
   display:none;
}
tr.no-border:hover i.action-icon{
   display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No need of Javascript/ jQuery for this, just use CSS:

```
tr i {
    opacity: 0;
}

tr:hover i {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: @JohnHascall This would hide show only the <i> element, not the <td> nor the <tr>

Comment: This is far simpler that the solution I posted. I'm going to check this out :)

Comment: Javascript is powerful, but should be used when needed. CSS is definitely enough for this kind of things :)

Comment: You're right! I'm not very proficient in the frontend side. I'll accept your answer once I test it.

Comment: I accepted CosX's answer because it didn't use opacity. I have another CSS that uses opacity to make the button look transparent when it shows and not transparent at all when you hover over it (not the row but the specific icon). Also you have tons of points and he still doesn't. But thanks for you great answer! :)

Comment: @Avi: fair enough. I've used `opacity` instead of `display` on purpose, because opacity will not "move" the objects near the button when you hide/show it, while display will. You won't notice it if it's alone in a <td>, but try putting other elements around it, and you will see. You can use `visibility: hidden`, eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
}
tr {
  border-top: 1px solid;
}
table {
  border: 1px solid;
}
i {
  display: none;
}
tr:hover i {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td><i>button</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dolor</td>
      <td>hello</td>
      <td><i>button</i></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lorem</td>
      <td>Ipsum</td>
      <td><i>button</i></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("td").on("hover", function(){
    if($(this).find("i").is(":visible"))
        $(this).find("i").hide();
    else
        $(this).find("i").show();
});
```

Comment: You better use `.find()` instead of `.children()`!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this tutorial](http://www.grobmeier.de/angular-js-the-show-on-mouseenter-hide-on-mouseleave-directive-31082012.html#.VUDKgq2qqko) I created a quite similar directive that instead of checking the parent for hover, it checks the grandparent (because the icon's parent is the `td` element and I want the `tr`). So the directive looks as follows:

```
angular.module('my.directives').directive('showOnGrandparentHover',
   function() {
      return {
         link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.hide(); // Start with icon hidden
            element.parent().parent().bind('mouseenter', function() {
               element.show();
            });
            element.parent().parent().bind('mouseleave', function() {
               element.hide();
            });
       }
   };
});
```

Then my HTML element looks like this:

Comment: You should post this to question! not as an answer!

Comment: No I don't. I wanted to create this question as a knowledge base. I didn't imagine getting so quick responses :)
But that's how SO says it should work, If you want to share experience - upload an answer to your question.

Comment: :D @Avi: FYI, in case you want to post a question and an answer like in this case, you can do it all at once: write both the question AND the answer and only then publish them ;) +1 on the question for the good intentions, BTW

Comment: @AndreaLigios - oh, I never noticed this option. I have done this with java many times but never got so many responses so quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

definitely CSS is the way to go.

however, please think of accessibility, if possible so add `tabindex="0"` to the download "button" and make it appear if it's focused, like so:

```
tr i[ng-click] {
  opacity: 0;
}

tr:hover i[ng-click],
tr i[ng-click]:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
```